# Apache Ignite Near Cache Always Missed

Tags: ignite, near-cache

When using a near cache everything will work fine until a second client (could be visor) attempts to connect or disconnect to the cluster while a cache operation is in process.

After the second client connects/disconnects, the original client will always miss the near cache until and the original client restarts. Almost as if the cluster informs the client their are issues and to keep the cluster as the source of truth.

We have been able to reproduce this by running our test and connecting/disconnect with visor. During a disconnect we can see a Timeout mentioned in the logs on the original client IgniteTxManager$NodeFailureTimeoutObject.

Below is a snippet of the logs with the org.apache.ignite.internal.processors suppressed.

> [2017-10-09 14:26:52.148] boot - 9955 DEBUG [http-nio-8081-exec-8] --- CacheHelper: Total time accessing cache ng-security-service-ORG_SPEC_CACHE for key * | value com.cache.model.PrefixCluster@78475a88: 0 millis
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.150] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridDiscoveryManager: Daemon node left topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4cc6c321-d9cc-4149-a6ef-cba68877a269, addrs=[10.70.255.8, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1], sockAddrs=[/172.17
>   .0.1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.70.255.8:0], discPort=0, order=57, intOrder=31, lastExchangeTime=1507577126368, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.150] boot - 9955 DEBUG [http-nio-8081-exec-8] --- OrgSpecCacheImpl: OrgSpec Cache Stats: OrgSpec ObjId: IgniteCacheProxy [delegate=GridNearCacheAdapter [], opCtx=null, restartFut=null] HitCount: 120, MissCount: 50, AvgReadTime: 
>   120, Eviction Count: 0
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.150] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridDeploymentPerVersionStore: Processing node departure event: DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4cc6c321-d9cc-4149-a6ef-cba68877a269, addrs=[10.70.255.8, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1], sockAddrs=[/172.17.0.1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.70.255.8:0], discPort=0, order=57, intOrder=31, lastExchangeTime=1507577126368, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true], topVer=58, nodeId8=2e573c60, msg=Node left: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4cc6c321-d9cc-4149-a6ef-cba68877a269, addrs=[10.70.255.8, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1], sockAddrs=[/172.17.0.1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.70.255.8:0], discPort=0, order=57, intOrder=31, lastExchangeTime=1507577126368, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true], type=NODE_LEFT, tstamp=1507577212142]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.163] boot - 9955  INFO [exchange-worker-#27%null%] --- time: Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=58, minorTopVer=0], crd=false, evt=11, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2e573c60-45f0-4429-a3fa-068489663148, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.70.242.138, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[port-svc-inc-13.tw-test.net/10.70.242.138:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=56, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1507576971754, loc=true, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true], evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=2e573c60-45f0-4429-a3fa-068489663148, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.70.242.138, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[port-svc-inc-13.tw-test.net/10.70.242.138:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=56, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1507576971754, loc=true, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true], customEvt=null]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.164] boot - 9955  INFO [exchange-worker-#27%null%] --- GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture: Snapshot initialization completed [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=58, minorTopVer=0], time=0ms]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.164] boot - 9955  INFO [exchange-worker-#27%null%] --- GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture: Snapshot initialization completed [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=58, minorTopVer=0], time=0ms]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.164] boot - 9955  INFO [exchange-worker-#27%null%] --- time: Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=58, minorTopVer=0], crd=false]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.203] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridDeploymentLocalStore: Deployment meta for local deployment: GridDeploymentMetadata [depMode=SHARED, alias=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1, clsName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1, userVer=null, sndNodeId=2e573c60-45f0-4429-a3fa-068489663148, clsLdrId=null, clsLdr=null, participants=null, parentLdr=null, record=true, nodeFilter=null, seqNum=n/a]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.203] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- LocalDeploymentSpi: Registering [ldrRsrcs={org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f={org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.T2=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.T2, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionHistorySuppliersMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionHistorySuppliersMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap, java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList=java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList, org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheMetricsCollectorTask=org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheMetricsCollectorTask, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionsToReloadMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionsToReloadMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor$1, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionCountersMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionCountersMap}}, ldr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f, rsrc=class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.203] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- LocalDeploymentSpi: Resources to register: {org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1}
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.203] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- LocalDeploymentSpi: New resources: {org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1}
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.203] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- LocalDeploymentSpi: Removing resources [clsLdrToIgnore=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f, rsrcs={org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1}]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.203] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridDeploymentLocalStore: Retrieved auto-loaded resource from spi: DeploymentResourceAdapter [name=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1, rsrcCls=class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1, clsLdr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.203] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridDeploymentLocalStore: Acquired deployment class: GridDeployment [ts=1507576972855, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f, clsLdrId=6d9e6920f51-2e573c60-45f0-4429-a3fa-068489663148, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=0]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.203] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridResourceProcessor: Injecting resources [target=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1@61ea2cff]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.211] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridDeploymentLocalStore: Deployment meta for local deployment: GridDeploymentMetadata [depMode=SHARED, alias=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1, clsName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1, userVer=null, sndNodeId=2e573c60-45f0-4429-a3fa-068489663148, clsLdrId=null, clsLdr=null, participants=null, parentLdr=null, record=true, nodeFilter=null, seqNum=n/a]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.211] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- LocalDeploymentSpi: Registering [ldrRsrcs={org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f={org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.T2=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.T2, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionHistorySuppliersMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionHistorySuppliersMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap, java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList=java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList, org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheMetricsCollectorTask=org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheMetricsCollectorTask, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionsToReloadMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionsToReloadMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor$1, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionCountersMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionCountersMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1}}, ldr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f, rsrc=class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.211] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- LocalDeploymentSpi: Resources to register: {org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1}
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.211] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- LocalDeploymentSpi: New resources: {org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1}
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.211] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- LocalDeploymentSpi: Removing resources [clsLdrToIgnore=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f, rsrcs={org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1}]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.211] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridDeploymentLocalStore: Retrieved auto-loaded resource from spi: DeploymentResourceAdapter [name=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1, rsrcCls=class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1, clsLdr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.212] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridDeploymentLocalStore: Acquired deployment class: GridDeployment [ts=1507576972855, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f, clsLdrId=6d9e6920f51-2e573c60-45f0-4429-a3fa-068489663148, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=0]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.212] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridResourceProcessor: Injecting resources [target=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1@1ff41d49]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.213] boot - 9955 DEBUG [pub-#34%null%] --- GridClosureProcessor: Grid runnable started: closure-proc-worker
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.213] boot - 9955 DEBUG [pub-#34%null%] --- GridClosureProcessor: Grid runnable finished normally: closure-proc-worker
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.216] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- TcpCommunicationSpi: Forcing NIO client close since node has left [nodeId=4cc6c321-d9cc-4149-a6ef-cba68877a269, client=GridTcpNioCommunicationClient [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=3, bytesRcvd=714, bytesSent=6799, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=1557230104, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#20%null%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=1, sentCnt=1, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4cc6c321-d9cc-4149-a6ef-cba68877a269, addrs=[10.70.255.8, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1], sockAddrs=[/172.17.0.1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.70.255.8:0], discPort=0, order=57, intOrder=31, lastExchangeTime=1507577126368, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true], connected=true, connectCnt=0, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=1, sentCnt=1, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4cc6c321-d9cc-4149-a6ef-cba68877a269, addrs=[10.70.255.8, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1], sockAddrs=[/172.17.0.1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.70.255.8:0], discPort=0, order=57, intOrder=31, lastExchangeTime=1507577126368, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true], connected=true, connectCnt=0, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/10.70.242.138:47100, rmtAddr=/10.70.255.8:53916, createTime=1507577162587, closeTime=0, bytesSent=6799, bytesRcvd=714, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1507577162587, lastSndTime=1507577162697, lastRcvTime=1507577162617, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@9573b3b, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=true]], super=GridAbstractCommunicationClient [lastUsed=1507577162587, closed=false, connIdx=0]]]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.217] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- TcpCommunicationSpi: Offered move [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=3, bytesRcvd=714, bytesSent=6799, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=1557230104, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#20%null%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=1, sentCnt=1, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4cc6c321-d9cc-4149-a6ef-cba68877a269, addrs=[10.70.255.8, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1], sockAddrs=[/172.17.0.1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.70.255.8:0], discPort=0, order=57, intOrder=31, lastExchangeTime=1507577126368, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true], connected=true, connectCnt=0, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=1, sentCnt=1, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4cc6c321-d9cc-4149-a6ef-cba68877a269, addrs=[10.70.255.8, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1], sockAddrs=[/172.17.0.1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.70.255.8:0], discPort=0, order=57, intOrder=31, lastExchangeTime=1507577126368, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true], connected=true, connectCnt=0, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/10.70.242.138:47100, rmtAddr=/10.70.255.8:53916, createTime=1507577162587, closeTime=0, bytesSent=6799, bytesRcvd=714, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1507577162587, lastSndTime=1507577162697, lastRcvTime=1507577162617, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@9573b3b, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=true]], fut=NioOperationFuture [op=CLOSE]]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.217] boot - 9955 DEBUG [disco-event-worker-#26%null%] --- GridIoManager: Removed messages from discovery startup delay list (sender node left topology): null
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.217] boot - 9955 DEBUG [pub-#35%null%] --- GridClosureProcessor: Grid runnable started: closure-proc-worker
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.217] boot - 9955 DEBUG [pub-#35%null%] --- GridClosureProcessor: Grid runnable finished normally: closure-proc-worker
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.283] boot - 9955 DEBUG [grid-timeout-worker-#15%null%] --- GridTimeoutProcessor: Timeout has occurred: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxManager$NodeFailureTimeoutObject@7ff59c90
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.284] boot - 9955 DEBUG [grid-timeout-worker-#15%null%] --- GridDeploymentLocalStore: Deployment meta for local deployment: GridDeploymentMetadata [depMode=SHARED, alias=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxManager$NodeFailureTimeoutObject$2, clsName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxManager$NodeFailureTimeoutObject$2, userVer=null, sndNodeId=2e573c60-45f0-4429-a3fa-068489663148, clsLdrId=null, clsLdr=null, participants=null, parentLdr=null, record=true, nodeFilter=null, seqNum=n/a]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.285] boot - 9955 DEBUG [grid-timeout-worker-#15%null%] --- LocalDeploymentSpi: Registering [ldrRsrcs={org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f={org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.T2=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.T2, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionHistorySuppliersMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionHistorySuppliersMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap, java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList=java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList, org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheMetricsCollectorTask=org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheMetricsCollectorTask, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionsToReloadMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionsToReloadMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor$1, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$1$1, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionCountersMap=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.IgniteDhtPartitionCountersMap, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$TaskDiscoveryListener$1}}, ldr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f, rsrc=class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxManager$NodeFailureTimeoutObject$2]
>   2017-10-09 14:26:52.285] boot - 9955 DEBUG [grid-timeout-worker-#15%null%] --- GridDeploymentLocalStore: Retrieved auto-loaded resource from spi: DeploymentResourceAdapter [name=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxManager$NodeFailureTimeoutObject$2, rsrcCls=class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxManager$NodeFailureTimeoutObject$2, clsLdr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.285] boot - 9955 DEBUG [grid-timeout-worker-#15%null%] --- GridDeploymentLocalStore: Acquired deployment class: GridDeployment [ts=1507576972855, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7adf9f5f, clsLdrId=6d9e6920f51-2e573c60-45f0-4429-a3fa-068489663148, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=0]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.285] boot - 9955 DEBUG [grid-timeout-worker-#15%null%] --- GridResourceProcessor: Injecting resources [target=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxManager$NodeFailureTimeoutObject$2@3f183e4]
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.317] boot - 9955 DEBUG [http-nio-8081-exec-8] --- CacheHelper: Total time accessing cache ng-security-service-ORG_SPEC_CACHE for key * | value com.cache.model.PrefixCluster@6954be5d: 167 millis
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.319] boot - 9955 DEBUG [http-nio-8081-exec-8] --- OrgSpecCacheImpl: OrgSpec Cache Stats: OrgSpec ObjId: IgniteCacheProxy [delegate=GridNearCacheAdapter [], opCtx=null, restartFut=null] HitCount: 126, MissCount: 53, AvgReadTime: 126, Eviction Count: 0
>   [2017-10-09 14:26:52.321] boot - 9955 DEBUG [sys-#36%null%] --- GridClosureProcessor: Grid runnable started: closure-proc-worker

My question is, is this expected behavior? Can we get the near cache not be bypassed, or in the least re-establish using the near cache after the bad client disconnects.

Comment: How do you determine what the client had a misses in near cache and data was loaded from data node?

Comment: @NikolayTikhonov We have a test set up to judge performance, this test will measure time for each call and report back. We consistently get <1 millisecond on calls to near cache. Using visor we can see the read count increment for each call. Then when a bad client connects it jumps up to 40 milliseconds. Viewing the results in visor we can see the near cache miss count increments for each call.

Comment: Bad client should not affect to near cache on other client. Probably, you have very often topology change. Could you share full logs from client node?

Comment: @NikolayTikhonov , i've updated the question with a little more detail and some logs. We had to target to the categories, so let me know if i should be looking in a different area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out their is a bug with the near cache. When a topology change occurs it can wipe out the topology version on the NearCacheGridEntry which will cause every call to check if the entry is valid to return false.

Bug has been submitted https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6767